# SED: open/read files in directory

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a directory with files like this:

```
one.xml
two.xml
three.xml
```

etc.

I want to open/read all files and save some values to a new file (e.g. `new.txt`)

The result in the `new.txt` should be (filename/value of first line):

```
one value of first line
two value of first line
three value of first line
```

etc.

Comment: Simply make a little program (perl, python, java). `sed` is a bit misplaced here, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first line using `head`.  The following should work:

```
for i in *.xml; do echo -n "$(basename "$i" ".xml") "; head -1 "$i" ; done >> new.txt
```

Comment: I think you should remove double quotes from `for` argument to make it work. Otherwise it processes all files as a single argument and `basename` fails.

Comment: `head -1`/`tail -1` is deprecated, the use of `-n 1` is encouraged. `echo -n` is not portable either, just use `printf`. And don't forget to quote `$i`, just in case.

Comment: It is almost correct. The file extension is still there

Comment: @saromba See the edit.  Added the suffix for `basename`.

Answer (score 1):

sed can do this just fine, with a little help from find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.xml" -exec sed -n 1p "{}" ";"
```

(YMMV with respect to quoting the arguments to exec).

What this is does is use `1p` to print the first line of each file, and combine that with `-n` which suppresses normal output which, in this case, would be to print every line of the file.